# Suddenly no output on second monitor but detected

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I'm running 22.04.1 on an i5-8500 with a GT 1030, for which I'm using the the "NVIDIA driver metapackage nvidia-driver-470" (as reported by "Software & Updates - Additional Drivers")

I'm facing a rather weird issue. I've been using two external monitors for years now without any issues whatsoever. This morning, one of them simply wouldn't display anything. The monitor itself works fine, as there are no issues on Windows, and it also sporadically works for a few seconds when I turn the monitor off and on again.

Ubuntu does *detect* the monitor just fine. It detects it and it's set as the primary display even. It just won't output anything to it.

The problem appears during boot and login screen as well.

The second monitor works just fine.

I've already searched for this a bit, but all I could find was related to energy saving settings on Laptops, which isn't really applicable in my case since this is a desktop PC or a second monitor not being detected, which also is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue and have *partly* resolved it.  I fix it every time by going to Settings > Displays.  Display mode shows "Single Display".  I change it to "Mirror", apply, and the 2nd monitor comes on.  I accept changes, then change mode to "Join Displays", readjust the positions (Every time. The settings just won't "stick"), apply, and again once everything shows I click "accept".

If I try to do "Join Displays" mode to begin with, it doesn't work right.  I have to "Mirror" first.

I realize this doesn't fully fix the issue since you have to do it every time you've come back to the computer.  But at least it's a work-around.  Let me know if this helps at all.